# Does Scala Async do everything that Clojure's core.async does?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, macros, clojure

In [this presentation](https://github.com/strangeloop/StrangeLoop2013/blob/master/slides/sessions/Haller-ScalaAsync.pdf) Haller talks about Scala Async.

In [this presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/clojure-core-async?utm_source=dlvr.it&utm_medium=twitter) - Rich Hickey talks about Clojure's core.async.

Both appear to be macros - but Scala Async (correct me if I'm wrong) doesn't seem to have a concept of CSP or channels.

What are the differences between Scala Async and Clojure's core.async?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

core.async's `go` macro provides non-blocking put and take operations for 'channels', which are otherwise-blocking many-to-many queues.

Scala Async's `async` macro provides a non-blocking wait operation for results of ordinary `Future`s.

So the answer is no. core.async is about *communication* between concurrent processes, while Scala Async deals with simply waiting for concurrent processes to finish. core.async can easily simulate the functionality of Scala Async, but not vice-versa.